# Restoring NuGet packages

Tags: nuget

I have a `C#` solution containing several projects. Some of projects has referenced nuget packages. Whole solution (but no downloaded dlls) is tracked by git repository.

After cloning it to other place and trying to build nuget asks if it should download missing packages. After downloading there are still several referenced library missing.

I can fix it one by one doing following steps:

1. Remove reference
2. Remove package in packages.config file
3. Install this package again by nuget

Is there any better way to do this? I tried reinstalling all nuget packages, but my Visual Studion crashes. After restarting and retrying it left me with more missing packages.

Another way to do this is running:

1. PM> Uninstall-Package {Name}
2. PM> Install-Package {Name}

for each missing package. By missing package I mean all packages with yellow mark. I can't install it without uninstall command, becasue nuget says it is already referenced.

Answer (score 1):

If you try running the following from the command line does it restore all the packages?

```
nuget.exe restore YourSolution.sln
```

If not then it sounds like there's some packages that are missing from your project's packages.config file.

You could try the updating the packages with the reinstall parameter from the PowerShell console.

```
Update-Package –reinstall <packageName>
```

You can also restrict this to one project if you want to by using the -ProjectName parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because of the incorrect path of the .dll in your .csproj. The package restore downloads the packages to the local directory. 
It doesn't change the reference path of the assembly in the .csproj, meaning that the project will still try to locate dlls on the local directory. The yellow mark means the project is unable to locate the assembly.

Unload the project, right click on project and select "Edit .csproj", and verify the path of missing dlls.
For example - If you have NUnit,

```
<Reference Include="nunit.framework">
      <HintPath>..\packages\NUnit.3.6.1\lib\net45\nunit.framework.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

verify if the dll is present inside "\packages\NUnit.3.6.1\lib\net45" directory.